# ASP.NET MVC View Engine Resolution Sequence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, viewengine

I created a simple ASP.NET MVC version 1.0 application. I have a ProductController which has one action Index. In the view, I created a corresponding Index.aspx under Product subfolder.

Then I referenced the Spark dll and created Index.spark under the same Product view folder. The Application_Start looks like

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new Spark.Web.Mvc.SparkViewFactory());

        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());

    }
```

My expectation is that since the Spark engine registers before default WebFormViewEngine, when browse the Index action in Product controller, the Spark engine should be used, and WebFormViewEngine should be used for all other urls.

However, the test shows that the Index action for Product controller also uses the WebFormViewEngine.

If I comment out the registration of WebFormViewEnginer (the last line in the code), I can see that the Index action is rendered by Spark engine and the rest urls generates an error (since the defualt engine is gone), it proves that all my Spark code is correct.

Now my question is how the view engine is resolved? Why the registration sequence does not take effect?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The order in which you register the view engines doesn't matter (much).  Rather, view engines take a set of `ViewLocationFormats`, and if a particular view path fits the formatted name, that engine will be used.  Only if you have conflicting formats does the registration order matter.

In the case of spark, views should have the `.spark` extension.  `WebFormViewEngine` will respond to any with `.aspx` or `.ascx` extensions.  And of course, as mentioned above, you can override any of this by changing the `ViewLocationFormats` supplied to the individual view engines.

---

**Updated:**

I took a look through the source of both `SparkViewFactory` and `WebFormViewEngine` (or more specifically, `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine`, which the latter derives from), and I can tell you why you're seeing this strange behaviour.

First of all, the `Find` method in the `ViewEngineCollection` class works like this (simplified):

```
foreach (IViewEngine engine in Items) {
    // Query engine for cached view
}

foreach (IViewEngine engine in Items) {
    // Query engine for uncached view
}
```

In other words, it will always try to find a cached view, in **any** engine, before resorting to uncached mode.

The way in which individual view engines implement this is the second overload of the `FindView` method, which takes a `bool` argument named `useCache`.

**However**, and here's where it all gets weird - the `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` and `SparkViewEngine` have very different ideas of what the `useCache` argument means.  There's too much code to repost here but the basic idea is:

- The `SparkViewFactory` will look **only** in the cache if `useCache` is `true`.  If it doesn't find anything, it automatically returns a "cache miss result" - i.e. nothing.  On the other hand, if `useCache` is `false`, it will not look in the cache at all, it will skip the cache-checking step and go through the normal motions to resolve and create an actual view.
- The `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine`, on the other hand, looks in the cache if `useCache` is `true`, and if it doesn't find the view in the cache, **it goes off and creates a new one and adds that to the cache.**

Both of these approaches work with respect to the way `ViewEngineCollection` performs its search.

- In the case of spark, it "misses" on the first iteration of view engines, but "hits" on the second, and after that the view is added to the cache.  No problem.
- In the case of `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine`, it "misses" internally but returns a "hit" anyway on the first iteration, at which point the view is now cached.

So you should be able to see where the problem is here.  The `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` only *appears* to be taking precedence over the `SparkViewEngine` because the former always succeeds on the **first** (cached) iteration, but Spark only succeeds on the **second** (uncached) iteration.

In plain English, Spark really does get asked first, but replies: *"No, I don't have that view **yet**.  Try it without the cache instead."* WebForms gets asked second, but automatically says *"I **didn't** have that view, but I went and made one for you anyway, here it is."*.  And from that point on, the `WebFormViewEngine` always gets priority because it has the view cached and Spark doesn't.

---

Summary: Spark **is** getting priority, but due to a quirk in the way Spark treats the `useCache` argument, it's getting left in the dust when the Web Form engine is active at the same time.  Either WebForm is over-eager or Spark is lazy, depending on your perspective.

Simply put, the solution is **not to have conflicting views!**  If you've registered multiple view engines, then you should be treating any view name which can be handled by either/both of them as **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: To summarize: Removing Index.aspx file will make Index.spark used.

Comment: I still do not quite understand. The ViewLocationFormats is defined in VirtualPathProviderViewEngine, it is an internal implementation specific to a view engine. 

If the ASP.NET MVC has multiple view engines registered, it will query one by one to see whether a view engine can handle the request. The first view engine answers yes process the request. In my case, both Spark and WebFormViewEngine can handle the request since Index.aspx and Index.spark are there. So why does WebForViewEngine alwasy take precedence?

Comment: @intangible02: Tested and verified, I dug through the source and now have an explanation for that, take a look.

Comment: @Aaronaught: fantastic answer! Just hope the view engines will standardize the behavior in the future.

Comment: @Aaronaught Your conclusions about the behavior of useCache and WebFormViewEngine are incorrect. Sorry for the additional answer, but can't include code and not enough chars length for response in comment. I'll update answer to clarify.

Comment: @lou: Thank you for the clarification.  My conclusions *are* correct as this question is about version 1.0 and I was going directly by the source code.  I suppose your answer may be correct as well for version 2; questions about ASP.NET MVC 2 are currently tagged `asp.net-mvc-2` while the `asp.net-mvc` tag implies version 1.

Comment: What a great answer, sorry if this seems like fluff, but it's very comprehensive and great study material for the lifecycle of how ASP.NET MVC queries the view engines!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... Nope - all due respect webforms doesn't do anything beyond a cache-check when useCache is true. Same as Spark.

Actually - I think someone might have moved my cheese... Spark might have had a quirk added causing a false cache-miss during the useCache==true pass. If that's true it's more of a bug than different rules applied to that parameter.

---

Updated:

I was looking at MVC 2 originally - which is why I implied @Aaronaught's conclusions were incorrect. MVC 2 does not return a view on the first pass where useCache==true, which is different in MVC 1.0 which will resolve and populate.

So difference is between the way ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and ASP.NET MVC 2 are implemented. Spark and MVC 2 treat the useCache flag the same, and the order they are registered will give them priority.