# ASP.NET MVC Route based on Web Browser/Device (e.g. iPhone)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible, from within ASP.NET MVC, to route to different controllers or actions based on the accessing device/browser?

I'm thinking of setting up alternative actions and views for *some* parts of my website in case it is accessed from the iPhone, to optimize display and functionality of it. I don't want to create a completely separate project for the iPhone though as the majority of the site is fine on any device.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: This can help you
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Mix: Mobile Web Sites with ASP.NET MVC and the Mobile Browser Definition File](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=ddbbf4e4-0d35-4c01-846f-94aaa13b2b4e)

Don't know if the above helps as I havn't watched it yet.

And this one;

[How Would I Change ASP.NET MVC Views Based on Device Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387354/how-would-i-change-asp-net-mvc-views-based-on-device-type)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a route constraint class:

```
public class UserAgentConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly string _requiredUserAgent;

    public UserAgentConstraint(string agentParam)
    {
        _requiredUserAgent = agentParam;
    }
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.UserAgent != null &&
               httpContext.Request.UserAgent.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(_requiredUserAgent);
    }
}
```

And then enforce the constraint to one of the routes like so:

```
      routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional},
           constraints: new {customConstraint = new UserAgentConstraint("Chrome")},
           namespaces: new[] {"MyNamespace.MVC"}
           );
```

You could then create another route pointing to a controller with the same name in another namespace with a different or no constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be a custom action filter.

All you have to do is inherit from `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`, and override the `IsValidRequest` class.

```
public class [IphoneRequest] : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
             // return true/false if device is iphone
```

Then in your controller

```
[IphoneRequest]
public ActionResult Index()
```

Comment: Oh and i think to work out if the device is iphone:

string agent = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
return agent.Contains("iPhone")