# MVC3 - Different device, different view, same controller

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC3, I am developing a mobile-enabled website, that has different views for tablets. My controllers can stay the same for both the iPad and the mobile site. How would I go about doing this? Do I have to duplicate controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How Would I Change ASP.NET MVC Views Based on Device Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387354/how-would-i-change-asp-net-mvc-views-based-on-device-type)

You should look here, seems he has the same problem/question as you.

Comment: Thank you ! That seems to cover it well.