# Creating a MVC mobile site with same model and controller as main site

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to produce a mobile site for a client, based on their existing ASP.NET MVC 3 Azure implementation. I'm happy that I can use the existing controllers and models, but I want a new set of views, JS, style sheets, and static content, that display less of the data. I'm pretty certain I can do this with just view changes.

Is there any way in which I can achieve some sort of view switch to pickup a different set for the mobile URL m.clientname.com - or even switch them at build time?

Can I product a view only project? And link in the DLL's from the main project ?

I guess the last resort is starting a new project based on the same files, but with new views?

Any thoughts on if anyone has done this would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387354/how-would-i-change-asp-net-mvc-views-based-on-device-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was covered by Scott Hanselman a while ago:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx

Comment: there is something there I can use, but I don't want to go down the browercaps route - above perhas prompting the user that there may be a site thats better for their device. I really don't like getting a cutdown site just because I'm using a mobile.

Comment: If you don't want to use browsercaps, then maybe you need to go down the responsive design route. Try this for a very brief primer: http://www.creode.co.uk/blog/responsive-design-vs-dedicated-mobile-sites/

Comment: no I really don't want to go down that route either - because I want to change the actual content. I want to deliver a separate site on m. and allow the user to swtich (by picking a url, a link on each site to the other, and maybe a preference cookie)