# Creating a custom ViewResult that displays a different view based on platform in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make my Action return a different view for different platforms, respecting the routing config. If I create a custom ViewResult, will I override the FindView method? And if so, how can I modify the View that is automatically found?

For example: HomeController.About action would display View\Home\About.cshtml on computer, View\Home\AboutTablet.cshtml on a tablet, and View\Home\AboutMobile.cshtml on a cell phone

Comment: Why not specify a different style sheet instead of a different view?  That seems to fly in the face of the MVC pattern.

Comment: Because it's different content on these pages and we'd like to use the same controllers.

Comment: MVC4 can probably do this a lot better using DisplayModes, if you can wait for MVC4 to RTM.

Comment: @vcsjones I'd prefer to somewhat emulate that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a NuGet for you: [MobileViewEngines](http://nuget.org/packages/MobileViewEngines). ScottHa covered it in a [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx). It's spec compatible with ASP.NET MVC 4 where you can get rid of it easily because this functionality is built-in.

Comment: I'm not sure it's going to work right out of the box, but the source code should be enough to get me going. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could define an Actionfilter like this:

```
public class SetDeviceDependantView : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Only works on ViewResults...
        ViewResultBase viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (viewResult != null)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            // Default the viewname to the action name
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewResult.ViewName))
                viewResult.ViewName = filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            // Add suffix according to device type
            if (IsTablet(filterContext.HttpContext))
                viewResult.ViewName += "Tablet";
            else if (IsMobile(filterContext.HttpContext))
                viewResult.ViewName += "Mobile";
        }
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    private static bool IsMobile(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;
    }

    private static bool IsTablet(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // this requires the 51degrees "Device Data" package: http://51degrees.mobi/Products/DeviceData/PropertyDictionary.aspx
        var isTablet = httpContext.Request.Browser["IsTablet"];
        return isTablet != null && isTablet.Equals(bool.TrueString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Then you can either annotate the required Actions / Controllers like this:

```
[SetDeviceDependantView]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

Or set it globally in the global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new SetDeviceDependantView());
}
```

Note, that I'm relying here on the 51degrees library to detect the tablet, you could consider using a different technique. However, that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this pre-MVC4, check out this blog post from Christopher Bennage

http://dev.bennage.com/blog/2012/04/27/render-action/

I was specially interested in the ContentTypeAwareResult class, which looks like it might be what you are looking for.

https://github.com/liike/reference-application/blob/master/MileageStats.Web/ContentTypeAwareResult.cs

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own `ViewEngine` (probably deriving it from the one you're using) and override `FindView` and `FindPartialView`. You can provide fallbacks (i.e., use generic view if no tablet one is found).

Most trouble will be in defining the criteria to differentiate between different "modes".

Answer (score 0):

Building a custom ViewEngine is a preferred approach in MVC3 for this requirement. For you info - MVC4 support this feature out of the box.

For more information about device specific view, a similar answer is posted here on StackOverflow itself https://stackoverflow.com/a/1387555/125651